# CSS Alternatives to style=“display:none”

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, menu, css-animations

I'm trying to have a fade down animation on menu and submenu but it only works on the first one. I'm using a 
***transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;visibility: hidden;margin-top:-10px;*** on nav >div> ul > li  > ul and ***margin-top:0px;opacity: 1;visibility: visible;*** with hover. The problem comes from `nav li > ul ul {display: none;}`. It seems that CSS can't animate between display: none; and display: block; and i don't know how to replace display: none;

here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5a9gedgt/2/) with the display:none and the no animation on the last submenu and here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5a9gedgt/1/) with visibility:hidden; the animation works but i've got wired effect

Is there a way to have this animation work on all the submenus ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, looks like you were one level off:

```css
nav{position: relative;}
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
}
li.has_children{
  position:relative;
}
li.has_children > ul{
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  visibility:hidden;
  margin-top:-10px;
  opacity:0;
  background-color: green;
}
li.has_children:hover > ul{
  margin-top:0px;
  visibility:visible;
  opacity:1;
}
nav > div > ul> li > ul > li > ul{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:100%;
  /* You may want to add a width */
}
nav > div > ul > li {
  float: left;
}
nav >div> ul > li  > a:hover{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar" class="navbar">
<nav id="site-navigation" class="navigation main-navigation" role="navigation">
<div class="menu-mega-container">
<ul id="menu-mega" class="nav-menu">
        <li><a href="#">My awesome button</a></li>
        <li class="has_children"><a href="#">My awesome button</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">awesome link nº 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">awesome link nº 2</a></li>
                <li class="has_children"><a href="#">awesome link nº 3</a>
                <ul>
                <li><a href="#">awesome link nº 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">awesome link nº 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">awesome link nº 3</a></li>
            </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @user3617339 but even if it's working good in the example your code doesn't work in my wordpress site. I've got just one problem and it's nav li > ul ul {
    display: none;
} cause it seems CSS  can't animate between display: none; and display: block;

Comment: and i can't delete nav li > ul ul { display: none; } without having big submenu issue. Is there something that can replace that display:none without affect css animation ?

Comment: Yes. Use visibility:hidden; opacity:0; and visibility:visible; opacity:1;  instead of display

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the `display` property with `opacity` to get the same animation effect. Even though `display` doesn't animate, it gets applied unnoticed since `opacity`'s start and end points are being animated.

In your case, it looks like all you need to do is add another rule set like so:

```
nav#site-navigation li > ul ul {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;

  /* these will fix your jumping issue */
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

nav#site-navigation li > ul ul {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Also, you should consider animating only `transform` properties. When you animate things like `margin-top` or width/height/etc it causes repaints/reflows in the browser which hinder performance. `transform` animation is done with the GPU instead.